# Where should I ask questions about the installation of SSL certificates?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have questions regarding the installation of an SSL certificates, but I wasn't sure what site I should be using to ask these questions.  Should I be using Server Fault, Information Security, Stack Overflow, or another site to assist with this?

Comment: @iLuvLogix Please don't edit links out of spam posts; flag as spam instead. (This particular spam answer was deleted already, but a note for the future.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a programming issue. It is an issue of using/installing a program.

If you want to install it on a server in a business environment, you can ask on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com). Otherwise on [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Comment: how about [http://security.stackexchange.com/](http://security.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: That would be more apropriate if you have a question about SSL itself and not about installing it

Comment: Glad to know that... you have already got my +1.

Comment: Depending on the nature of the question, possibly [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security-certificate).